# HP Pavilion does not boot

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, boot, hp-pavilion

I just reset my new AMD HP Pavilion on windows 10 and it shows a message "Automatic Repair couldn't repair your PC"

The really strange thing is I want to install windows 7 pro which I have a copy of. I then take out the hard drive and format it fully with cmd on another W7 laptop. When I then installed the formatted drive back into the Hp and switched on shows the Automatic Repair screen again even though the drive was fully formatted? I'm really lost on this one.

Comment: Did you remove the recovery partition?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot format a hard disk - you format only partitions on a hard disk when using Windows.

The proper way to go is to clean the disk.

On command prompt from installation DVD/USB you execute:

**diskpart.exe**

then

**select disk 0** (!!disk 0 is first disk, disk 1 is second disk ...!! You can use "list disk" to display disks and their sizes)

then

**clean**

This will wipe all partition/formatting information.

Now you can reboot and install Windows 7 to a "fresh" disk.